# IPN - Handle custom characters

Tags: php, url, paypal, paypal-ipn

working with paypal´s IPN-notifiction i try to pass a serialized custom-array, i am not sure why, but i am getting a violation-error sql, so this my query:

```
$test = array('cmd'=>'_xclick',
                        'business'=>'email@email.com',
                        'notify_url'=> 'url/to/ipn.php',
                        'item_name'=>'Pixel',
                        'amount'=>'1.00',
                        'currency_code'=>'USD',
                        'lc'=>'US',
                        'custom'=>serialize( array( "variable1" => $variable1,"variable2" => $variable2,
                                            "variable3" => $variable3,"variable4" => $variable4,
                                            "variable5" => $variable5)));


                        $url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?".http_build_query($test);

                        header("Location:".$url);
                        exit();



//later in ipn.php:
$custom = unserialize($_POST["custom"]);

    $variable1 = $_POST['variable1'];
    $variable2 = $_POST['variable2'];
    $variable3 = $_POST['variable3'];
    $variable4 = $_POST['variable4'];
    $variable5 = $_POST['variable5'];

    try
    {
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO firsttable(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5)
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
                                    $stmt->bindParam(1, $value1);
                                    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value2);
                                    $stmt->bindParam(3, $value3);   
                                    $stmt->bindParam(4, $value4);
                                    $stmt->bindParam(5, $value5);


                                                $value1 = $variable1;
                                                $value2 = $variable2;
                                                $value3 = $variable3;
                                                $value4 = $variable4;
                                                $value5 = $variable5;
                                                $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        $variable .= "Failure: " . $exception->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

Just returns this error:

```
Failure: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL,'.',NULL)'
```

Is it because "custom" is longer than 200 character´s ?? or what did i wrong??

Greetings!!

Comment: What does `$variable1` equal after unserializing? Is $_POST['custom'] more than 200 characters?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you posted is not storing the content of `$custom` and you should use single quote instead of double quote on your prepared statement to avoid injection. Your issue looks like depending on the content of the $value1..n that are not defined anywhere if you want to save value of $variable1..n instead bind that variables instead of $value1..n

anyway the content of the unserialized custom field is in $custom NOT in the $_POST['variable1'];..$_POST['variablen']; you can use $custom[n] to get the value.

note that paypal custom field has max 255 characters length

Another note, you should urlencode when you serialize to avoid unallowed characters